# JS checkbox enable/disable input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**Q:** How to enable/disable input with checkbox?

Each checkbox enable/disable input next to it. Number of groups is various (i = 1,2,3, ...n). 
Default setting is that inputs are disabled and checkbox unchecked.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tDCB9/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="">
<input type="text" name="name11" class="stat" value="">
<input type="text" name="name12" class="stat" value="">
<input type="text" name="name13" class="stat" value="">
```

**JS:**

```
$("input[name="group1"][type="checkbox"]").click(function() {
    $("input[name="name11"][type="text"]").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("input[name="name12"][type="text"]").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("input[name="name13"][type="text"]").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tDCB9/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a change() handler for the checkboxes and then use nextUntil() to find out the input fields to be disabled

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(input:text)').prop('disabled', !this.checked)
}).change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d5Vds/)

Comment: why not `$(this).nextUntil(':checkbox')` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Because that would include the `<br>` tag.

Comment: @David Yes. didnt notice that br :-)

Comment: @David so why not `$(this).nextUntil('br')` ??

Comment: @RoyiNamir that is right... I was not sure about the last item... that is why I opted for the `input:text` selector

Answer (score 1):

your code works, it's just a question of simple quote / double quote,

```
$("input[name='group1'][type='checkbox']")
```

[Demo Corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/tDCB9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='group1'][type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $("input[name='name11'][type='text']").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    }
    else{
        $("input[name='name11'][type='text']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDCB9/13/).

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input').attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

You just need to separate the input groups in a container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name='group1'][type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $("input[name='name11'][type='text']").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("input[name='name12'][type='text']").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("input[name='name13'][type='text']").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple selector :

```
 $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('br').prop('disabled', !this.checked)
    }).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("input[name='group1'][type='checkbox']").click(function() {   
$("input[name='name11'][type='text']").attr("disabled", this.checked);
$("input[name='name12'][type='text']").attr("disabled", this.checked);
$("input[name='name13'][type='text']").attr("disabled", this.checked);
});
```